# How to force Angular to re-fetch data from the Backend for specific URLs?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Let's say I have 3 angular components:

- ProjectsComponent, which displays a list of projects, fetched from my backend.
- ProjectsFormComponent, which takes input from the user and saves a project to the backend.
- ProjectUpdateFormComponent, which takes input from the user and updates a project in the backend.

**The issue I am facing:**

Whenever I create a new project or update a project, it gets updated in the backend immediately and angular returns from `ProjectsFormComponent` to `ProjectsComponent`, but the data it shows is outdated. It does not reflect the newly added project. I have to either refresh the page or switch to another component and back to `ProjectsComponent` to reflect the changes. The same goes for `ProjectUpdateFormComponent`.

**Things I have tried in vain:**

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],         // forces auto-refresh of current URL with real-time data
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**ProjectsFormComponent**

```
  // Force-refresh of data from the back-end
  refresh(): void {
    window.location.reload();
  }

  addProject(): void {
    this.projectService.newProject(this.project).subscribe(data => {
      alert("Project: " + this.project.name + " has been created successfully!");
      this.refresh();
      this.router.navigate(['/projects']);
    })
  }
```

**ProjectComponent**

```
  constructor(private router: Router, private projectService: ProjectService, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
      return false;
    };
  }
```

**How do I tell angular to always reload specific pages such as `ProjectsComponent` always from the backend instead of fetching old data from its cache?**

Comment: Do you have a service worker or something?

Comment: Yes, I have a service called ```ProjectService``` which takes the data from ```ProjectFormComponent``` and sends it to the backend.

Comment: Ask yourself this;

1. How are the projects fethed the first time?
2. When are they fetched?
3. How can I ensure that they are fetched every time the specific projects page is visited? 

You already have all the code you need, just fetch it at the proper times!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your refresh method to call a service to fetch the data from the server. In the same way you are adding a new project.

```
refresh() {
    this._projectService.getProjects().subscribe(data => this.projects = data);
}
```

OR

Have the backend return the updated data when you add a new one and then subscribe to the response.

```
addProject() {
    this._projectService.addProject(project).subscribe(data => this.projects = data)
}
```

If you are able to switch back to the component to refetch the data, your answer probably lies there. How are you getting it (maybe within ngOnInit?) if so pull this out of the ngOnInit and put it in its own function. Then you can call this in multiple places and reuse it on component initialisation and when you add a new project.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Your code snippets helped me fully solve my problem.